# how to create BMP image from binary data in Python?

Tags: python, image, audio

Suppose I already read binary data from a binary file, how can I create a BMP image from that binary data?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a definition of the bitmap file format [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) among other places. Use the `struct` module to create the necessary headers. Because the format is uncompressed it is very easy to write out. The color information must come in BGR order, bottom line to top line, and each line must be padded with zeros to a multiple of 4 bytes.

Or if you'd rather do it the easy way, [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) knows how to [read and write BMP](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-bmp.htm).